# How to unlink language and regional settings

Tags: 20.04, settings, language-support, locale

I want my Ubuntu 20.04 set up with US English language settings, but my formats force me to use Dutch or German (mixing up the languages on my system). I just need US Language settings with Belgian formats in English.

In the Region & Language settings, the language is set to English (United States). For the format (number notation, date notation and currency), I need Belgian settings but I'm limited to Belgium (Dutch) or Belgium (German). I would've expected to see French in that list as well, but even that is missing...
What I really need is all the Belgian formats but completely in English, so no mix with Dutch, German or French.

Is there any way that I can separate the regional settings from the language settings?

Belgian settings are:
Euro (€) for currency.
Choice between comma (,) or dot (.) for decimal separator.
Correct date notation: day / month / year

If I want the date to be displayed in English and have the right currency, I can only choose English (Ireland). Ireland is the only EU country with English as official language, but that doesn't allow me to configure the comma as decimal separator.
If I want Belgian settings, the system date will be shown in either Dutch or German, while the rest of my system is in English.

Comment: Regional settings depend on the standards of one or more (official) languages of any given territory.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. There are plenty expats around the world who work in a different language than the official language of the country. Other operating systems don't have this bug.
If you already set the language, there shouldn't be a need to re-declare another language for simple formatting purposes. If that is the case, this is a serious bug.

Comment: Not a bug, not even by a long shot. RE: Other OSes I don't know what you're talking about. Windows is even more restricted. With Ubuntu at least you can very easily install additional languages and have one for the overall desktop interface but choose and entirely different one for regional formats.

Comment: This also conflicts with the claim that Linux is so highly customizable. There must be some solution...
Can't I somehow edit the English (Ireland) formatting so I get English (Belgium) with the correct formatting?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Actually no, I run Windows too and I don't have this problem on it. That being said, Windows vs Linux is not the topic of discussion. I'm just looking for a solution on Ubuntu.

Comment: Now you're ranting. But there is indeed a solution, several actually.

Comment: I will try the export LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8 in my .profile. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @ChanganAuto It's a combination of the answers given in that link. If you post it as answer, I'll choose is as accepted answer.